# empty request object in django

Tags: django, http, request, uwsgi

I just inherited a broken django setup, 1.9, python 2.7, nginx,
uWSGI, RHEL 6. First thing I observed, the views are not receiving
anything in the request object, e.g.:

```
(Pdb) print request
<WSGIRequest: GET '/'>
```

Other django systems I've worked with I always get something, e.g.:

```
(Pdb) print request
<WSGIRequest
path:/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'csrftoken': 'ieefjZZJjeif993i4nfmnkZZKJ',
 'messages': '2f148ec0f66f94740a8ff273dd544b554d28c96c$[["__json_message",0,20,"The
tool \\"U7316\\" was added successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The
tool \\"U7321\\" was added successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The
tool \\"SEMA116\\" was added
successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The tool \\"U7324\\" was added
successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The tool \\"U7324\\" was
changed successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The tool \\"SEMA116\\"
was changed successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The tool
\\"U7331\\" was added successfully."],["__json_message",0,20,"The tool
\\"SEMA207\\" was added successfully."]]',
 'sessionid': 'xg254b6ki5m981n8oko4n88jnqsj0m1y'},
META:{'Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render': '/tmp/launch-FIgPyl/Render',
.
.
.
```

I've never seen this before. What could be causing this? Where would I
begin to look?

Comment: Do you have all the middleware classes configured properly in your `settings.py ` file?

Comment: When I print a request object I usually get the same result as you. That doesn't mean there's nothing in it, it just means the default tostring for a request object prints that much information. Are you sure the previous projects didn't have a more verbose tostring overridden for request objects? Or some added settings for verbose tostring? Can you confirm that the object actually doesn't have these properties?

Comment: Here's what I have: `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',`

Comment: Also, the other system I have is 1.5 this one is 1.9, and the 1.5 system 1s running apache with wsgi version 3.4, and the 1.9 system is nginx with uWSGI version 2.0.12.

Comment: No, neither one has a tostring defined. I am pretty sure the request object is empty as when I pass it into login() nothing happens.Whereas on my other system I get a login screen.

Comment: You say 'I just integrated a broken django setup' - is the request object empty when you are testing or in normal site usage or both?

Comment: What do you mean by 'integrated a broken django setup'. What did you integrate? Was it working before?

Comment: Please show your uWSGI config, nginx config and `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: I meant "inherited" not "integrated"

Comment: So this was a red herring - in django 1.8 they changed the `__repr__` method on HttpRequest so it's not printed. It is in fact there. But the problem I am facing now is that there is no user attr. I would expect this: `(Pdb) request.user <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x10c424850>` But I get this: `(Pdb) request.user *** AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`